# Unable to run python code in Azure function

Tags: python-3.x, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I have **init**.py and blobquickstartv12.py within the same Azure Function "Test-v3". While **init**.py is a blob trigger, "blobquickstartv12.py " has the python code that I want to run. The only way I am able to run my code in blobquickstartv12.py is if I paste the entire code within the main() function of **init**.py.

I tried using `from blobquickstartv12 import load` where load is a function in my blobquickstartv12.py code but that gave me Exception: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'blobquickstartv12'

Can anyone tell me how can I call my custom code from within **init**.py
This is how the structure  of my Azure Function looks like:

Here is my code in **init**.py:

```
import azure.functions as func
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime
from pandas import ExcelFile
from pandas import ExcelWriter
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService
import pyodbc
import sys
import os
from io import StringIO
import pkgutil
from . import blobquickstartv12

def main(myblob: func.InputStream):
    logging.info(f"Python blob trigger function processed blob \n"
                 f"Name: {myblob.name}\n"
                 f"Blob Size: {myblob.length} bytes")
load=blobquickstartv12.load()
```

Here is my code for blobquickstart.py:

```
class load:

    #CODE FOR CONNECTING TO THE SQL DATABASE
    SERVER = 'xxxxxx.database.windows.net'
    DATABASE = 'XYZ'
    username = 'USERNAME'
    pwd = 'PASSWORD'
    driver= '{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}'
    cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER='+driver+';SERVER='+SERVER+';PORT=1433;DATABASE='+DATABASE+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ pwd)
    cursor = cnxn.cursor()
    print("Connected to Azure SQL")
    #sqlcommand = ("INSERT INTO Stage.File(File_ID,File_type) VALUES (1235,'D')")
    Curr_dt = datetime.now()

    BLOB_STORAGEACCOUNTNAME="blobstorage"
    BLOB_STORAGEACCOUNTKEY="AccountKey"
    BLOBNAME="BlobName"
    CONTAINERNAME= "ContainerName"
```

[image]

Comment: Please notice this is imported inside the module, so you need to use `from . import blobquickstartv12`.

Comment: This is the offcial doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python#import-behavior

Comment: Can you work it out now?

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

Please check the structure. On my side it is no problem. The code can import blobquickstartv12 fine.

[image]

[image]

This is the structure of azure function:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python#folder-structure

This is the doc of how to import:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python#import-behavior

**Original Answer:**

import module in the module should be like this:

For example, I have a dog.py and I want to use it.

This is the dog.py:

```
class Dog:
    def __init__(self,name):
        super().__init__()
        self.name = name
    def showdog(self):
        print("This is a dog!")
```

In the `_init_.py`, you should use this:

```
from . import dog
mydog = dog.Dog("Woodie")
```

It work fine on my side.

This is the structure:

[image]

Comment: I am getting the error ImportError: cannot import name 'blobquickstartv12' from '__main__' (__init__.py)

Comment: Can you tell me how I should frame my code to call blobquickstartv12 from __init__.py in Azure Function?

Comment: @RahulBanerjee Maybe you can check the structure. This is the offcial doc of how to import, you can try other way. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python#import-behavior But on my side, `from . import blobquickstartv12` is no problem.